# How to order a collection by a property first and then by another property regardless of tie on first property?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, grouping

What I am trying to achieve is order the `OrderSummary` by highest `Amount` first and then display all other `Order`(s) in the collection for the given account one after another regardless of the `Amount`. Expected outcome is in the code snippet..

```
 public class OrderSummary
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    }

    public class Worker
    {
        public List<OrderSummary> Orders { get; set; }

        public Worker()
        {
            Orders = new List<OrderSummary>()
            {
                new OrderSummary() {FirstName = "James", Amount = 10.00m},
                new OrderSummary() {FirstName = "Thomas", Amount = 11.00m},
                new OrderSummary() {FirstName = "Leon", Amount = 13.00m},
                new OrderSummary() {FirstName = "Lori", Amount = 14.00m},
                new OrderSummary() {FirstName = "Thomas", Amount = 16.00m},
                new OrderSummary() {FirstName = "Thomas", Amount = 6.00m},
                new OrderSummary() {FirstName = "James", Amount = 19.00m}
            };
        }

        //sorted by highest amount first
        //then place firstname together regardless of the amount

        //Expected Outcome
        /*
           James 19 -- highest amount followed by all other orders for James regardless of the amount.
         * james 10
         * thomas 16
         * thomas 11
         * thomas 6
         * lori 14
         * leon 13
         */
    }
```

My approach was to get all elements that occurs more than once, then locate at which index the elements are except for the first one, remove it from the index, and add it to first element's index + 1.. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: ``var orders = Orders.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Amount);``

Comment: that would only solve the first part... I got stuck when it came to placing all the other order by same person one after another regardless of the amount..

Comment: You want to groupby Name, then sort the groups by highest Amount, then flatten the groups back into a list with SelectMany.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GroupBy` creates groups in the order that they appear in the source collection, so you can first order by amount, then group by name, then "flatten" the groups:

```
var results = Orders.OrderByDescending(o => o.Amount)
                    .GroupBy(o => o.FistName)  // the groupings will be in order of the largest amount
                    .SelectMany(g => g);       // flatten the groups
```

Comment: I can't resist saying thank-you for this. Very neat solution! Thank-you!

Comment: This puts the highest amount first in a group, but I don't see how it puts the other elements in their original order (this sorts them by amount).

Comment: It's a handy feature of `GroupBy` It creates groups as it encounters them - so it will "scan" the data in amount order, creating new groups as it goes but leaving the grouped data in amount order. So the name with the highest amount is the first "group".  `SelectMany` then iterates each group and outputs the items.  Since the groups are in amount order that's how `SelectMany` outputs them.

Comment: I know, but my point was "inside" the group, the elements are sorted by amount in descending order. While the way OP describes it he wants just to "move" the highest at the first position. It might be OP fault to explain his requirement though.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying.  I inferred that requirement form the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var list = Orders.OrderByDescending(y => y.Amount).GroupBy(x => x.FirstName).Select(x=>x.Key).ToList();
```

This is ordering the records descending, then it is grouping them by `FirstName`, so you will have the one with the highest `Amount` first, then the others.

Comment: Thank-you but not exactly what I was looking for. I do not want to group by name, I just want the elements of the collection with same name placed  one after another after the first one appears as an element themselves.

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler I was pretty close huh?

Comment: very close indeed, all you needed was to use selectMany instead. Learned sth new already, going to be good day! Thanks for taking time to help me with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var maxAmount = Orders.Max(o => o.Amount);
var maxPos = Orders.IndexOf(maxAmount);
var maxOrder = Orders[maxPos];
Orders.RemoveAt(maxPos);
Orders.Insert(0, maxOrder);
```

**EDIT**

I didn't get that "one after another" would mean "grouped by name"...

Comment: No I don't want them grouped, each will still be a separate element but will be placed right after the first element appears (highest amount) in the collection.

Comment: That's how I understood it. But apparently you want them in a specific order (first all of james, then thomas...), and I don't think you made that clear enough. You just said the highest amount order should come first, which my code does.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have an example for you using .Net fiddle

Here it is

[Answer To Question](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aYyWvo)

Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

> My approach was to get all elements that occurs more than once, then locate at which index the elements are except for the first one, remove it from the index, and add it to first element's index + 1

Here is the LINQ way of doing exactly what are you describing:

```
var query = from o in Orders
            group o by o.FirstName into g
            let top = g.Aggregate((a, b) => b.Amount > a.Amount ? b : a)
            from o in Enumerable.Repeat(top, 1).Concat(g.Where(o => o != top))
            select o;
```

You start by grouping the Orders by FirstName, then for each group you locate the element with the maximum Amount using [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate(v=vs.110).aspx), put it first in a group and append the others. Finally flatten the result.